# Event on Chrome Application Restart

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I found out how to manage the *onClose* event for Chrome App, it works fine for closing, but it doesn`t work for restart the application.
By Restart I mean: *right click* on Chrom App window and click on "*Reload Application*".

Piece of my *background.js*

```
chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
    'state': "maximized"
},
function(aWindow) {
      aWindow.onClosed.addListener(function(e) {
          console.log('close');
      });
});
```

Surely there are not methods like *onRestart()*, according to [Google App Docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window)

Has somebody found a solution for this?

*As for me during development it is more comfortable to use **"Restart"**, rather than **"Close"** + **"Start"***

Comment: Try this: in `onClosed` write a value to `chrome.storage.local`, check it on start (read and delete) - if it didn't exist the app was restarted. It won't let you do something before the restart, though.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for the trick. Not a great solution, but anyway, this can be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @**Xan**, I`ll correct his url to [*chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched*](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_runtime#event-onLaunched)

There is a way to define whether application is restarted, on the app`s start:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function(launchData) {
    if (launchData.source == "reload") {
        console.log('restarted');
    }
    chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
        'state': "maximized"
    });
    // ...
});
```

That is actually not the answer for my question. In terms of: **Restart = Close + Start**. I`m interested to fire some code, on **Close**, not on Start.

Anyway this solution is cleaner than proposed by @**wOxxOm** in comments

Answer (score 0):

There's an API event that seems to fit your description: [`chrome.app.runtime.onRestarted`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_runtime#event-onRestarted)

> Fired at Chrome startup to apps that were running when Chrome last shut down, or when apps have been requested to restart from their previous state for other reasons (e.g. when the user revokes access to an app's retained files the runtime will restart the app). In these situations if apps do not have an onRestarted handler they will be sent an onLaunched event instead.

Comment: That is the case for whole Chrome restart. 
This works for: right click  ->  "Simulate browser restart"
But sadly doesn`t work for app restart :(

Comment: @AndriiBogachenko This actually sounds like a bug: the function's description specifically mentions "apps have been requested to restart from their previous state".